# Windows Phone 8.1 SQLite delete error: no pk

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1, primary-key

im trying to delete a row in a sql db using SQLite for Windows Phone. This is my dbHelper Class:

```
public void DeleteContact(int Id)
    {
        using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection("models.db"))
        {

            var existingconact = dbConn.Query<item>("select * from item where Id =" + Id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (existingconact != null)
            {
                dbConn.RunInTransaction(() =>
                {
                    dbConn.Delete(existingconact);
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is my code:

```
Database_controller controll = new Database_controller();
        int id = controll.ReadContact(infoVar.modelid).Id;
        controll.DeleteContact(id);

        Frame.GoBack();
```

But every time i tap the delete button in the app, this error pops up:

Cannot delete item: it has no PK

I've tried to add a Primary Key and Auto Increasment to the Id column of my table, because the guy in the [tutorial](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sqlite-Sample-for-Windows-83d88433) i found, had the following picture in it:
[image: table structure]

Do you know how to fix this problem?

Edit: my model class looks like this:

```
public class item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Hersteller { get; set; }
    public double EWD { get; set; }
    public string TTiefe { get; set; }
    public string TAbstand1 { get; set; }
    public string TAbstand2 { get; set; }
    public string HTiefe { get; set; }
    public string HAbstand1 { get; set; }
    public string HAbstand2 { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SenderNr { get; set; }
    public bool Segler { get; set; }
    public double Spannweite { get; set;}
    public double Gewicht { get; set; }
    public double Flaeche { get; set; }
    public double FBelastung { get; set; }


    public item()
    {
        //Constructor
    }

    public item(string name, int ID, string hersteller, double ewd, string tTiefe, string tAbstand1, string tAbstand2, string hTiefe, string hAbstand1, string hAbstand2, int senderNr, bool segler, double spannweite, double gewicht, double flaeche, double fBelastung)
    {
        Name = name;
        Hersteller = hersteller;
        Id = ID;
        EWD = ewd;
        TTiefe = tTiefe;
        TAbstand1 = tAbstand1;
        TAbstand2 = tAbstand2;
        HTiefe = hTiefe;
        HAbstand1 = hAbstand1;
        HAbstand2 = hAbstand2;
        SenderNr = senderNr;
        Segler = segler;
        Spannweite = spannweite;
        Gewicht = gewicht;
        Flaeche = flaeche;
        FBelastung = fBelastung;

    }
}
```

Comment: How you defined your Model class?

Comment: You need to mark your `Id` property with `[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]` attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but where? In the DeleteContact-Method, or in the sql Table?

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked :) I had to add it in the item class. You really helped me a lot